# How to dynamically add list items to an Foundation Accordion Menu

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

Foundation had an accordion-menu and after the initial menu has been setup and effectuated by calling $(...).foundation() the menu looks fine. See [Zurb Foundation documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/accordion-menu.html).

Now I do want to alter the menu somewhere later after an AJAX call but calling the foundation() function gives the following error:

> Tried to initialize accordion-menu on an element that already has a
>   Foundation plugin

Also: the menu layout is completely wrong; the styles is-accordion-submenu-parent and is-accordion-submenu are never applied. No events are attached.

What is the correct way to insert another li element to an existing accordion-menu and have it render and function correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reinitialize the plugin after adding by adding the following code.

```
Foundation.reInit('accordion');
```

for details see http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html#initializing